# Is it possible to have two different text colors in the same CSS a:after element?

Tags: css

Here's [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Omahz.png) of what I'm working with, and its main css below. Basically I'm trying to figure out if I can make a similar link but for GitHub where main background is black while text inside is white, and text part that is outside is still normal black. Thanks for your time!

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #121314;
  position: relative;
}
a:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 60%;
  left: -0.1em;
  right: -0.1em;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: top 200ms cubic-bezier(0, .8, .13, 1);
  background-color:#D7090B
}

a:hover:after {
  top: 0%;
}

p2 a:after {
  background-color: rgb(56,161,243);
}
```

Comment: @Temani Afif thanks for linking other threads, the are useful but I can't seem to figure out how to apply it to my specific example. Any chance for further help? :)

Comment: here is a a basic example: https://jsfiddle.net/8vLfo4gu/

Comment: @Temani Afif Much appreciated! Thank you so much for your help!! Have a wonderful day!